# Error tyring to add a parameter in MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to create a report in MS Visual Studio and use the DateClosed as a parameter so that a user can select on 'DateClosed'.  The error I am getting says:

> Error Message:  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The select satement is below is based on a view that I had to convert a string (DateClosed) to a datatime data type.

```
  
SELECT        GrantNumber, GrantAmount, GrantDate, NatureOfGrant, SpecialInstructions, FullName, GMP, GrantType, Name, DateClosed
FROM            V_WSF_GrantMakingPartnersGrants
ORDER BY DateClosed DESC
```

I am really confused because the 'ClosedDate' above is returning the value as a datetime data type.  I can't cast it again, because it already sees it as a date.  This is making no sense to me.

Can anyone tell me how to add the parameter into MS Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you are getting the data from - SQL Server or Oracle? So you want to pass the date? Ie, you enter 02/02/2012 and then click to generate report?

If you are passing to Oracle, you might have to use the sql function TO_DATE(xxxx). The same thing may apply to SQL Server but that is not an area I'm not familiar with. Therefore:

..order by DateClosed may have to read like this:

to_date(DateClosed, 'yyyy/mm/dd')

The 2nd parameter - must match the date format that you are sending in...

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the dateTime.formate to specify the format type on the dataBase..
like "YYYY-MM-dd".  make sure the format is the same date format you are using on your DataBase string date.

I think this will solve your problem.